# Can the chromatic number of a graph be defined by the chromatic number of its subgraph(s)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I am a novice when it comes to graph theory. Now i'm solving different questions where you get a graph and should determine the chromatic number and chromatic polynomial for that graph. I'm stuck at this particular graph:

[image]

I started with isolating the "trickiest" sub graph "g" which happened to also be a wheel graph with an even amount of vertices n. And according to the internet, a wheel graph with this property has a chromatic number of 4, yes?

My big issue is when i check the correct answer of the question it says that the chromatic number of the entire graph G is 3. Did i incorrectly assume that the chromatic number of G couldn't be less than the chromatic number of g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are correct, the chromatic number of that graph is at least $4$, and your argument is completely valid.